# How to use '+' to concat string in JSON data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've a code like this:

```
jQuery.each(images, function (k, v) {
    v = v.split(':');

    data.questions.push({
        source: questionAssetPath + v[0],
        match: v[1],
        mouse: mouseAssetPath + v[2] + '.png'
    });

    data.answers.push({
        answer: v[1],
        match: v[1]
    });
});
```

When I run a grunt task (browserify:js), I've got this error:

```
ParseError: Unexpected token +
```

Please help me figure out of this.

Thanks you.

**UPDATE:**
I've solved it myself. Thanks guys. I've noticed that I can't use `+` operator with objects (wtf with me)

```
images = [
    "maria-ozawa.png:MariaOzawa:1",
    "aoi-125239.png:Aoi:2",
    "sasha-grey.png:SashaGrey:3"
];

jQuery.each(images, function (k, v) {
    v = v.split(':');
    v[0] = questionAssetPath + v[0];
    v[2] = mouseAssetPath + v[2] + '.png';
    data.questions.push({source: v[0], match: v[1], mouse: v[2]});
    data.answers.push({answer: v[1], match: v[1]});
});
```

Comment: Please post some sample data as well

Comment: Why not concatenate it in the variable before you build the JSON?

Comment: @Exception Why would you do that?

Comment: Seems that you have character ```+``` in your JSON, so provide JSON example where this error is happened.

Comment: I don't see any problem with this code. Maybe the problem comes from your data.

Comment: @BinaryBrain..i just misjudged the code after formatting now it is clear..

Answer (score 1):

```
 Query.each(images, function (k, v) {
        v = v.split(':');
        questionAssetPath = questionAssetPath.concat(v[0])
        data.questions.push({source: questionAssetPath, match: v[1], mouse: mouseAssetPath + v[2] + '.png'});
        data.answers.push({answer: v[1], match: v[1]});
    });
```

That will get rid of the need of using '+' and will solve the error

See the [JavaScript String concat() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_string.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Check your **data** because this seems to work fine:

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ar82mwv0/)**

```
var images = ["a:b:c","d:e:f"];
var data = {
    questions:[], 
    answers:[]   
};
var questionAssetPath = "c:\\abc\\";
var mouseAssetPath = "c:\\def\\";

$.each(images, function (k, v) {
    v = v.split(':');
    data.questions.push({source: questionAssetPath + v[0], match: v[1], mouse: mouseAssetPath + v[2] + '.png'});
    data.answers.push({answer: v[1], match: v[1]});
});

console.log(data);
```